# Order of each element in the given group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a little bit confused with this problem: let $G:=\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$. I have to find the order of each element in the group

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}=(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)$

Does it mean that I have to multiply by a number s.t. each of the sets becomes (0,0)?

Comment: Each of what sets?  You have to multiple/add each element by itself untion the result is $(0,0)$.  Example $(1,3)^2 = (1,3)+(1,3) = (0,2)$ and $(1,3)^3 = (2,2)+(1,3) = (1,1)$ and $(1,,,3)^4 = (1,1)+(1,3) = (0,0)$ so the order of $(1,3)$ is $4$.  That's the long tedious way.  If you are clever you might come up with a short cut.  Hint $(a,b)^k = (k*a \mod 2, k*b \mod 4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I perfectly understand what you mean in the last sentence but I can suggest the following; The order of an element $x$ is the least positive integer $n$ s.t. $x^n=1$ (in multiplicative notation) respectively $n\cdot x=0$ (in additive notation). Note that $n\cdot x$ means just $x+x+\dots+x$ $n$-times.

Take a random element and try to calculate such an $n$, as the Wanderer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the element $(0,1)$. The group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is additive, so the order is $4$. In fact, if you sum $(0,1)+(0,1)+(0,1)+(0,1)$, you will obtain the pair $(0,0)$, identity element for the above group.

Comment: so the 'x' coordinates are found by adding the set to itself until we get the first divisor of 2? and likewise the 'y' coordinates are found adding the set to itself until we get the first divisor of 4?.. Can you only add your own element to itself or can you mix it up with other elements as well?

Comment: "Can you only add your own set to itself"  What "sets" are you talking about?

Comment: Take $(1,3)$. Then you have $(1,3)+(1,3)=(0,2)$; moreover $(0,2)+(1,3)=(1,1)$ and $(1,1)+(1,3)=(0,0)$.

Comment: sorry I was confusing the cartesian products as sets, I think I should define them as elements

Comment: You should refer to the specific pairs as elements.  "sets" is simply incorrect.  And will lead to *huge* conceptual inaccuracies.